# Combine regular jQuery and iPad web-app specific functions

Tags: jquery, ipad, web-applications

Is there a way to combine regular jQuery and ipad web-app specific functions into one?
I have several functions on the same page that I'm calling twice. See one example below. Is there a way to combine both of these functions into one? So it will work on the web AND iPad?

Or I'm I stuck running multiple of the same functions?

```
    $forgotPass.bind('touchstart', function (event) {
        // prevent forgot password div from hiding on div click
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $forgotPass.click(function (event) {
        // prevent forgot password div from hiding on div click
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution on my own...see below:

```
$forgotPass.on('touchstart click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    // do something
});
```